# "Visit the exotic Sri Lanka first and the breathtaking Georgia in the next trip"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, adjectives

IS the 'the' right before an adjective 'exotic' and 'breathtaking' ?

Comment: It's not idiomatic US English.

Comment: but is it right or wrong? Don't care for the sentence construct..just wanted to know if the 'the' before the adjectives is right or wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

People say it, and it sounds OK, but using *the* is technically wrong, because (without the adjective) you wouldn't write:

> the Sri Lanka
>   or
>   the Georgia

I imagine it gets used in the manner of:

> Visit the exotic *country of* Sri Lanka first and the breathtaking *state of* Georgia *on your* next trip.

where using *the* would be fine.

Comment: And it's "on the next trip", not "in."

Comment: I suggest that it doesn't sound okay at all. If you include "the", it seems to implies that there are other Sri Lankas that are not exotic and that we should specifically visit the exotic one first.  You are right though; it would be fine if the name without the adjective included "The" (*eg.* "Visit the exotic West Indies ...").

Comment: @smatterer You example doesn't follow, because you would say "Visit *the* West Indies", not "Visit West Indies". *the* is required.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I think I badly need to brush up on my English basics.

Comment: @user3169 `... if the name without the adjective included "The" (eg.  ...").`

Comment: [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)) is also a country, and IMHO (coutry) Georgia  is much more breathtaking than a (state) Georgia :-) - maybe because I love mountains